# python: Elegant way to adopt class parameters?

Tags: python

Assume I have many expression similar to

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, a,b,c,d,e,f):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
```

Is there an elegant way to rewrite this?

Thanks!

Comment: starting from Python 3.7, you could use data-classes: https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html

Comment: okay Tryph, this is what I searched for. Put into an answer and I will check it as solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting from Python 3.7, It could be done using [data classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

```
@dataclass
class X:
    a: int
    b: str
    c: float
    # etc...
```

The `dataclass` decorator automatically generates the suitable `__init__` method.

---

As @Lie Ryan commented, you could also use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple):

```
>>> X = namedtuple('X', ('a', 'b', 'c'))
>>> x = X(1, 2, 3)
>>> x
X(a=1, b=2, c=3)
>>> x.a
1
```

It can even be inherited to add or overload methods:

```
>>> class X(namedtuple('XSuper', ('a', 'b', 'c'))):
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'pouet'
...     
>>> x = X(1, 2, 3)
>>> x
pouet
>>> x.a
1
```

---

The answer from [fountainhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55259615/2696355) is also a nice version-agnostic trick.

Comment: In older versions, there are also [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or [attrs](https://pypi.org/project/attrs/).

Answer (score 3):

You can try using named [generic arguments](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3):

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

and then:

```
x = X(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6)
```

But this is not good practice, as it gives you no control on what is actually passed.

Or:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        for key, value in zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], args):
            setattr(self, key, value)
```

and then:

```
x = X(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
```

BUT, as the [Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says:

> explicit is better than implicit

and your original code is good enough for that!

**EDIT**

Just to avoid overwriting *dangerous* properties, replace

```
setattr(self, key, value)
```

with

```
if not hasattr(self, key):
    setattr(self, key, value)
```

Comment: he is asking for args, not kwargs

Comment: You can add a statement like: `assert set(kwargs.keys()).issubset({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'})` or `if not set(kwargs.keys()).issubset({'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}): raise ArgumentError()` to enforce what can be passed into the class.

Comment: @E.Serra: `*args` can be handled similarly with `zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], args)` instead of `kwargs.items()`

Comment: I think that, as far as the OP's reasons are not clear, the best way to achieve that assignements is to be expicit. Any other solution wouldn't be "pythonic"

Comment: Alternatively, for the `kwargs` case, you can also do `self.__dict__.update(kwargs)`, or for `args` with `self.__dict__.update(dict(zip(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], args)))`

Comment: That would make whatever passed as kwarg work, and give no room for args/kwargs that don't behave as self.arg =arg

Answer (score 3):

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, a,b,c,d,e,f):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
        self.d = d
        self.e = e
        self.f = f

class X:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        arglist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        for i in range(0, len(arglist):
            try:
                setattr(self, arglist[i], args[i])
            except IndexError:
                raise Exception('Arg {} needs to be given a value'.format(arglist[i]))
```

Does not look like the most elegant thing everbut the longer the list the more simplified, also you only need to modify arglist and it will be reflected. Bad thing, you lose the signature (any non runtime checks you could make are lost, e.g. your IDE will freak out

Other suggestions include enumerate (cleaner way to work with indices).

Or you could just use zip, and do the check at the begginign:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        arglist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        if len(arglist) != len(args):
           raise CustomExceptino('Too few/many arguments...')
        for keyval_tuple in zip(arglist, args):
            setattr(self, keyval_tuple[0], keyval_tuple[1])
```

Note that you can still add arguments that don't behave this way:

```
    class X:
        def __init__(self, special_arg, *args):
            self.special_consequence = self.do_sth_with_special_arg(special_arg)
            arglist = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
            if len(arglist) != len(args):
               raise CustomExceptino('Too few/many arguments...')
            for keyval_tuple in zip(arglist, args):
                setattr(self, keyval_tuple[0], keyval_tuple[1])
```

Comment: prefer using `enumerate` builtin instead of `range(0, len(arglist)`

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
class X:
    def __init__(self, a,b,c,d,e,f):
        all_l = locals() # Let this be the first statement.
        for l in all_l:
            if (l != 'self'):
                self.__dict__[l] = all_l[l]
```

Output:

```
x = X(10,20,30,40,50,60)
print (x.d)

40
```